# Can't align Bootstrap 3 navbar items well for different mobile screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't center my navbar logo and menu on mobile. It looks good on desktop. Fiddle with code is at the bottom.

This is what it looks like on the iphone 5:

[image]

This is what it looks like on the iphone 6:

[image: This is what it looks like on the iPhone 6]

It looks yet worse on the iPad. I tried centering the logo, which is the first `li` element with `display:block;` and `margin:0 auto;` to no avail, even though I centered it's parent elements beforehand as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb2xj6p5/7/)

I can link the site to anyone interested in helping, since Fiddle doesn't display properly for some reason.

Comment: fiddle must diplay ok, please check your fiddle again, you made some mistakes in ordering elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add class

**center-block** and **img-responsive**

Here is jfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb2xj6p5/8/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/Ztm0behQInDnkGpy_6VQNCZ-C8TObFubrNfYi14TuSEPNKrV3G0_GvdxRowtf1U2n9aAuCxw25g3Ih9vXX5Y=s0">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1777/

Comment: It pulls the CSS rules form the class, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you come to chat with me, I'm going to vote your question.

Comment: Come to "Bootstrap navbar".